# Command-line tool to resolve node module

Tags: gnu-make, node-modules

I have a multi-repo/mono-repo makefile, and to express the dependencies between sub-repos and avoid rebuilding everything all the time, I want to refer to a dependent node module from my makefile. However, because of the way I have things set up, this module may be physically present under `node_modules` in the repo itself, or the parent repo, and so on up the tree.

In other words, I want to find a package according to the node module resolution algorithm. Something like this:

```
thing_to_build: $(shell find_node_module my-dependent-module)/dist/foobar.lib
```

Is there some obvious, simple, elegant way to do this?

Comment: I found out that I could sort of do this with `require.resolve(MODULE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Unluckily I don't know the node resolution algorithm, but here are three functions which try to find files from inside GNUmake:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# $1 filename
# $2 dirname (all subdirectories will be searched too)
search-down=$(if $(wildcard $2/$1),$(wildcard $2/$1),$(foreach dir,$(wildcard $2/*/.),$(call search-down,$1,$(subst /. ,,$(dir) ))))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# $1 filename
# $2 dirname within which (+subdirectories) filename is to be found
# $3 current directory
search-up=$(if $(wildcard $3/$1),$(wildcard $3/$1),$(if $(wildcard $3/$2),$(call search-down,$1,$3/$2),$(call search-up,$1,$2,$3/..)))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# $1 filename
# $2 dirname within which (+subdirectories) filename is to be found
search-above=$(firstword $(call search-up,$1,$2,$(wildcard .)))
```

`search-above` may be what you want: it looks for a file *filename*, starting from your current working directory upwards, on its way looking into every subdirectory *dirname* and down through all its children. I.e. if you are in `/home/torazaburo/foo/bar/baz` and you want to find `/home/torazaburo/foo/ding/dong/dang.js` then you `$(call search-above,dang.js,ding)`. You can even discriminate further, by giving `$(call search-above,dang.js,ding/dong)` which will start the search downward only from `/home/torazaburo/foo/ding/dong` and ignore any other subdirectory in `/home/torazaburo/foo/ding`.

Those functions (along with a sh*tload of others for configuration management inside GNUmake) can be found in [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt).